# How to call a member function via a pointer which is a class member itself

Tags: c++

My sample along with the comments is verbose enough, here it is:

```
class C
{
    public:
    void (*m_ffp)();    //free-function pointer (C member)    
    void (C::*m_mfp)(); //C::member-function pointer (C member)

    void doSomething() //from within the class:
    {        
        m_ffp();          //call the free function pointer
        (this->*m_mfp)(); //call the member-function pointer
    }
};

void (C::*g_mfp)(); //C::member-function pointer ('external', not a C-member)

int main()
{
    C c;

    //from outside the class:
    c.m_ffp();    //call the C-owned function pointer directly
    (c.*g_mfp)(); //call the non-member C::member-function pointer (external one)

    (c.*m_mfp)(); // error C2065 'm_mfp': undeclared identifier
    //how to call the C-member member-function pointer directly from outside the class?
}
```

So for a record - what's the syntax of a 'direct' call to an object's public member pointer to member-function (from outside the class of course / by a user)?

btw. this is not about validation/assignments any functions to these pointers (I do it in my real program), just please help me to get this compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `m_mfp` is a member of type `C`, you need to use the `.` operator to get the member:

```
(c.*m_mfp)(); // error C2065 'm_mfp': undeclared identifier
    ^ should be c.m_mfp
```

So the correct call looks like this:

```
(c.*c.m_mfp)();
```

Also, in C++17 and later, you can use [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to get rid of the ugly pointer-to-member syntax:

```
std::invoke(c.m_mfp, c);
```

Comment: Aah, such a little monster, yea, now it's working, thank you :) I will have to write some macro to beautify this (unfortunately not C++17).

Comment: @bloody, great! Please write a function template instead of a macro :)

Comment: Actually it can be a normal non-template function/wrapper (on condition that the compiler `inlines` it). But right, that's better than macro:)

Comment: `auto ptr = c.m_mfp;  (c.*ptr)();` - the call may possibly look nicer with an intermediate pointer declaration.

Answer (score 1):

```
C c1;
C c2;

void (C::*g_mfp)();

g_mfp = c1.m_mfp; // assign function pointer to what it's set to in c1
(c2.*g_mfp)();    // call the function using any C instance
```

If you want a pointer to a function bound to a specific instance, you can use `std::function` and `std::bind`:

```
std::function<void()> instance_func = std::bind(c1.m_mfp, c1);
instance_func();
```

Comment: That's right. I actually tried putting `std::function` as a C's member (instead of that ugly pointer) but it turned out to be slower - probably by an additional indirection inside `std::function` (couldn't afford - tree search / efficiency need).

Comment: @bloody Yeah, I does have some overhead. It checks that it has a stored callable before making the call (and throws if it doesn't) - so if it's time critical, skip it :-)

Comment: Or a lambda expression instead of `std::bind`: `auto func = [&c](){ auto mfp = c.m_mfp; (c.*mfp)(); };`

Comment: @bloody Yes, lambdas are nice and allows for additional logic to be added to the functor unlike if you just `std::bind` the instance and member function.